# NASM Assembly: checking length of string + confirming string is only made up of '0', '1', and '2' 's?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am relatively new to assembly and I'm trying to make a program that takes 2 command line arguments as input (2nd command line argument is a string) and checks that its between a length of 1 and 30. It also checks to see if the string is made up of the characters 0, 1, and 2 only. Any other character and it terminates. When I run the program, it simply outputs "Segmentation fault". From what ive gathered, this happens when I'm dealing with a part of memory that I shouldn't be messing with. I know my issue is somewhere within the loops, but I don't know where or why. Any suggestions on where my code is wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
global asm_main

SECTION .data
  lenError: db "Length of string must be between 1 and 30 (inclusive).",10,0
  argError: db "Only 2 command line arguments accepted.",10,0
  charError: db "Only characters '0', '1', and '2' are accepted.",10,0

SECTION .text
  global asm_main
  extern strlen
  extern printf

asm_main:
  enter 0,0
  pusha
  mov eax, dword [ebp+8]        ; argc
  cmp eax, dword 2              ; if argc == 2
  jne ERR_ARG
  popa
  mov ebx, dword [ebp+12]
  mov eax, [ebx+4]         ;eax has the string in it now  
  mov ecx, 0               ;initialize a counter
  LOOP1:
    cmp byte[eax], 0       ;end of string
    je DONE
    cmp byte[eax], '0'     ;check if char == 0
    je GO
    cmp byte[eax], '1'
    je GO
    cmp byte[eax], '2'
    je GO
    jmp ERR_CHAR
  GO:
    inc ecx       ; increase counter
    inc eax       ;next position in string
    cmp ecx, 30   
    jg ERR_LEN
  jmp LOOP1

  DONE:
    call print_string      ;there's more to come,
    jmp asm_main_end       ;but i want to find the error first

  ERR_CHAR:
    mov eax, charError
    call print_string
    jmp asm_main_end
  ERR_LEN:
    pop eax
    mov eax, lenError
    call print_string
    jmp asm_main_end

  ERR_ARG:
    mov eax, argError
    call print_string
    jmp asm_main_end

    asm_main_end:
      popa
      leave
      ret
```

UPDATE: i believe i have isolated the segmentation fault to asm_main_end, is there anything wrong with how i'm terminating from the program?

Comment: When you step through with a debugger what do you find?

Comment: sorry mate, but could you instruct me on how to use a debugger? im new to all this stuff.

Comment: Debugging isn't something that one can answer very easily. If you are taking a course have you spoken to a prof or teacher assistant. You may wish to ask them for information on debugging.

Comment: If only it were easier haha, we haven't gone over debugging for this course (i believe it is next semester?).

Comment: Why wait for semesters, go get a debugger (gdb?) and learn it. You are pretty close with the code you've got. Here is a hint: nasm has a specific way to move data or addresses of data into registers. Read the docs...

Comment: thanks for the hint frank, do you know what section of my code i should be looking into? (LOOP1, asm_main_end, etc...)

Comment: Teaching how to debug should be the *first* thing you do, right after writing "Hello world". If your teacher isn't smart enough to teach you how to do it, learn it yourself. It will save you a *lot* of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that causes the segmentation fault is the `popa` instruction after  `jne ERR_ARG` near the beginning of your function. If the branch is not taken, the registers are popped off the stack there, and then popped once again at `asm_main_end`.

```
asm_main:
  enter 0,0
  pusha
  mov eax, dword [ebp+8]       
  cmp eax, dword 2    
  jne ERR_ARG
  popa                   ; Do not pop here
  ;
  ;
  ;
  asm_main_end:
      popa               ; when popping here
      leave
      ret
```

The second `popa` will then remove the return address from the stack (in addition to filling most of the register with unrelated values), making the function return to an arbitrary location most likely not belonging to your program.  The program should then behave correctly if given a wrong number of arguments.

BTW: The pushing of registers (besides the pushing of ebp done by `enter`) should not be neccessary in your code.